# Number sections on leaflet

Tags: sectioning, numbering, leaflet

Using the `leaflet` class, sections are not numbered. If I try to use

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}. }
```

it doesn't change anything.

Is there a way to number sections in `leaflet`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`leaflet`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/leaflet) `documentclass` uses

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

on line `275`. To number the sections you can use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

and then you get numbered sections.

```
\documentclass{leaflet}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) I can't ping you with `@ ` though :)

Comment: Sure you can, if you can type my nick :-)